# How to create a function that reads all data from specific files from specific folders?

Tags: r, loops, file, directory, load

I have to create a function that can read all data for a specific region, for a specific local authority district and for a specific middle area. The function needs to follow this format:

**helper = function(df = NULL, rgn = NULL, lad = NULL, msoa = NULL, percent = NULL)**, where df is the dataframe, *rgn* is the parameter for a specific region, *lad* is  the parameter for specific local authority district, *msoa* is the parameter of specific middle area, and *percent* is the random percent I will select from the dataframe.

The thing is I have no clue on how to do this because of the way the folders are organized. Please take a look at the images below. **Image 1 are all the regions (rgn), Image 2 are all the local authority discrits (lad) from the region I selected and Image 3 are all the middle areas (msoa) from the lad I selected**. So, the path follows the structure "folder rgn -> folder lad -> msoa.Rdata.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Not only we have repeated codes (check E12000007), it is also possible that we have the same msoa.rdata in different lad folders.

How can I create a function that **can read all or specific regions/lad/msoa** that accounts for the issue I mentioned above according to this structure?

I am just starting at StackOverFlow and I have never experienced a folder structure like this before, so I am having a hard time to do this function in R.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

one solution, to run from the top directory (in your case: "90 Cross Project Data"):

```
files_to_load <- 
  list.files(path = '.',
             pattern = '.RData',
             recursive = TRUE
             ) 


Map(files_to_load, f = \(file_name) load(file_name, envir = .GlobalEnv))
```

- `Map(xs, f())` applies function `f` to each member of `xs`
- `\(x) x` is a shortcut for `function(x) x`
- argument `envir = .GlobalEnv` has the objects loaded into the global environment (your "workspace")
- *BTW: you have two folders for region 'East of England'*

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying! I did your code as:

df = Map(files_to_load, function(x) x) and it returned a list of all dataframes.

My doubt now is how to create a function with the parameters I mentioned above that return me what I want. For instance:

If I want the files from the region "England- North East", what should I do? Or if I want the files from the lad "Hartepool", what should I do? Or in case I want a specific Msoa.RData. That is what I am not getting it

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the `envir` argument which specifies where the objects contained in your files are loaded into. You don't need to do this when calling `load` from the global environment (your workspace), but from inside a function (here: `Map`) you do, as long as you want them globally visible.